# sending plus sign in php get url parameter

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-injection

i am sending parameters in url. but when try to write "0+880" variable in url the query is failing. this is the problem and here is a few of my codes

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
$yerId= $_GET['km'];

$sql = pg_query("SELECT  turu, hat_kesimi, ili, ilcesi, mahadi FROM $table WHERE km = $yerId");
if (!$sql) { 
    echo "Problem with query " . $sql . "<br/>"; 
    echo pg_last_error(); 
    exit(); 
}
```

and here are url's and what google returned url:

```
/weekend/index.php?dbname=tcdd&table=hemzemin_gecit&km=0^880#tab-1
```

google reaction:

Problem with query

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = double precision 
LINE 1: ...mi, ili, ilcesi, mahadi FROM hemzemin_gecit WHERE km = 0^880 
                                                                ^ 
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

another url:

```
/weekend/index.php?dbname=tcdd&table=hemzemin_gecit&km=0%2B880#tab-1
```

google reaction:

Problem with query

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer 
LINE 1: ...mi, ili, ilcesi, mahadi FROM hemzemin_gecit WHERE km = 0+880 
                                                                ^ 
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: That's an SQL Injection. And you're missing quotes around the string.

Answer (score 2):

There are *so many* things wrong  with this. Lets start with:

- You're not using PDO, you're using the legacy `pg_` functions;
- You're using `pg_query` with string interpolation. [Bobby says hi](http://bobby-tables.com/). See [SQL injection (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [SQL injection (PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php);
- You're not quoting `$yerId` as a literal e.g. `'$yerId'`, which you'd have to do to make this query work even *unsafely*

Please: [use PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or [at least `pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php).

Comment: thanks for your care, i will do it by using PDO but firstly I want to solve this problem. Isnt there anyway to send "+" in php get parameter

Comment: @fatih_turkey Use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) and pass the parameters as an array. That is the only acceptable way, other than PDO, to do what you want.

Comment: To be fair, there's nothing strictly "legacy" about non-PDO  database extensions in PHP. Right now, there's no process for maintainers to extend PDO beyond the core functions supported by all/most drivers, so new functions are still being added to MySQLi, ext/pg, etc for driver-specific functionality. Sadly, it's not possible to mix and match, either.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you shoud use:

```
 rawurlencode()
```

to encode the url, and

```
rawurldecode()
```

to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

When sending parameters, you should URLEncode them ""0+880" shoudl go as "0%2B880" else it will foul with the url.

Link to quickly encode / decode values for debugging / testing. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/